# Criterium for the representability of a functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, zariski-topology, representable-functor

Let $F: (Sch/S)^{op} \to Sets$ be a functor that is both a sheaf in the Zariski topology and has an open covering $(f_i: F_i \to F)_{i \in I}$, where each of the $F_i$ is representable.

In theorem 8.9 of Görtz-Wedhorn's book on algebraic geometry, it is proven that the functors $F_i$ glue to a scheme $X$. Then, because $F$ is a sheaf, the morphisms $f_i: F_i \to F$ glue to a morphism $f: X \to F$ - which the authors claim to be an isomorphism. Is there an elementary way to see that $f$ is an isomorphism? The book doesn't use universal objects, so an answer that doesn't address them would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the construction of $X$, we have "inclusions" $F_i \to X$. These glue to give a morphism $F \to X$, which is the inverse of the morphism $X \to F$ that you described.

Comment: how could I prove this? I am sorry, this things are all very new to me

Comment: If you're wondering how to prove that the compositions are the identities, you check this locally. For example, we take the composition $F \to X \to F$, precompose with the inclusion $F_i \to F$, and get the inclusion $F_i \to F$. Thus, this map $F \to X \to F$ is glued from the inclusions $F_i \to F$, and therefore is the identity.